# Junit UnitTests not saving to the database in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, junit5, spring-test

I am currently trying to change certain data in a JobOffer which works while running the application but I can't get it to work in a Unit test. My test is the following:

```java
@Test
public void changeJobOfferFieldsCorrectlyWithCorrectParameters() {
    JobOffer firstJobOffer = JobOfferBuilder.aJobOffer()
        .withId(null)
        .withCompany(user)
        .withAmountPerSession(96)
        .withJobDescription("Test description")
        .withJobFunction("Fullstack developer for Microsoft")
        .withVisible(true)
        .build();

    jobOfferDao.saveJobOffer(firstJobOffer);

    entityManager.clear();
    entityManager.flush();

    int changedAmountPerSession = firstJobOffer.getAmountPerSession() + 100;
    boolean changedVisibility = !firstJobOffer.isVisible();

    jobOfferDao.changeJobOfferFields(firstJobOffer.getId(), changedVisibility, changedAmountPerSession);

    entityManager.clear();
    entityManager.flush();

    Optional<JobOffer> retrievedJobOffer = jobOfferDao.findJobOfferById(firstJobOffer.getId());
    assertTrue(retrievedJobOffer.isPresent());
    JobOffer jobOffer = retrievedJobOffer.get();

    assertEquals(changedVisibility, jobOffer.isVisible());
    assertEquals(changedAmountPerSession, jobOffer.getAmountPerSession());
}
```

My `JobOfferDAOimpl` is the following:

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public void changeJobOfferFields(Long jobOfferId, Boolean visibility, int amountPerSession) {
    try {
        //TypedQuery<JobOffer> jobOfferQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("updateJobOffer", JobOffer.class);
        Query jobOfferQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("updateJobOffer");
        jobOfferQuery.setParameter("id", jobOfferId);
        jobOfferQuery.setParameter("visibility", visibility);
        jobOfferQuery.setParameter("amountPerSession", amountPerSession);
        jobOfferQuery.executeUpdate();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        throw new JobOfferNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

The `updateJobOffer` query is the following:

```java
@NamedQuery(name = "updateJobOffer", query = "UPDATE JobOffer offer SET offer.visible = :visibility, offer.amountPerSession = :amountPerSession WHERE offer.id = :id"),
```

So the data doesn't seem to update at all. So I'm guessing the `changeJobOfferFields` is wrong.

Comment: `NoResultException` will never get thrown inside `changeJobOfferfields`

Comment: Calling `flush` after `clear` is rather pointless, since `flush` flushes all changes to managed entities, but `clear` evicts all managed entities. You probably want to change the order of the two command. Even better is probably to use a `TransactionTemplate` for  each step in your test. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html

Comment: where exactly is your test failing?

Comment: @JensSchauder The clear and flush where the issue and changing that made it work the way I wanted it to work. But I don't really understand what they do and when you should use them? I tried to write an update and that didn't work without adding the clear and flush.

Comment: To be honest I can't completely explain the behaviour without further investigation either, but it is based on the entity life cycle of JPA. You might want to read up on that. Maybe the first part of this video does help a little as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zyqpo8gxSO0&list=PLk3sJ7f5UB1m3d4Y_c-Gerf4XqfpFPNRb&index=4